# Can a bad XLR cable break my usb audio interface?

Tags: noise, audio-interfaces, xlr, xlr-input, broken

From church, I took home two XLR Cables (16 AWG) that I considered may be broken, so that I could test them in a more controlled environment.

My **Focusrite Scarlett 2i4** has been working great in the past month with my own mic cables and MacBook Pro 16".

#### My Tests (In Sequence Order)

1. Home Mic Cable: As a control, with my home microphone and my mic XLR cable I recorded a bit of audio from my microphone and played it back. GOOD; just as expected.
2. XLRCable1: I was able to record and playback from my 2i4. GOOD; albeit it was quieter... XLRCable1 seems to be working.
3. XLRCable2: Soon after I plugged it into my 2i4 multiple things happened: **a)** the secondary input meter light started to flash (though I plugged into the primary input), **b)** I could not hear any microphone signal through my headphones (which was connected to the 2i4), **c)** I began to hear digital noise (like digital pulses) through my headphones.

My hunch: The XLRCable2 was so broken that it some how internally broken my audio interface.

Two Hours Later: It's been many hours of restarting my computer, unplugging and plugging in the audio interface and I can not get any audio to play (e.g. Spotify music), and I still hear digital noise.  Even when I go back to using my Home Mic Cable (my control), I cannot record any signal anymore!

**Q)** Can a bad XLR cable harm/break an audio interface?

Yes, I had phantom power on at the time, to power CloudLifter CL-1.

Answer (score 1):

Guesses…

XLR 1 has one broken wire, hot or cold, can't tell. This would in effect halve the power.

XLR 2 has a short between hot/cold & ground. This *might* potentially be giving the DAC 48v where it wasn't expecting it, possibly frying something.

For next time…

1. Take the barrels off & visually inspect the connections.
2. Use a continuity tester/multimeter to check each matching & non-matching terminal for breaks or shorts.

Comment: I came here to say this too. Personally, I use a dedicated cable tester: my Behringer CT-100 has been with me for years and has been so useful that I take it everywhere I'm working with audio.

Comment: Ah, a cable tester would have been helpful.  So if a bad mic cable can fry an audio interface, then using a cable tester would have been the better option for safety.